# Ideal way to set layout where the main content overlaps header and footer?

Tags: css

What is the ideal way to set this layout where the main contetnt overlaps header and footer? I could achieve it by setting `section 2` position absolute and `container` position relative. The issue I am having is `container` size is not increasing with respect to height of `section 2`.

html

```
<div class="contaier">
     <div class="section-1">...<div>
     <div class="section-2">...<div>
     <div class="section-3">...<div>
<div>
```

css

```
html{
height:100%
}
body{
min-height:100%;
}
.container{
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}

.section-1{
min-height:35%;
background-color: #1B80CE;

}
.section-2{
height:400px;
width:80%;
margin-left:10%;
position:absolute;
background-color: white;

}
.section-3{
min-height:65%;
background-color: #E8EBF0;
}
```

[image: layout]

Answer (score 2):

You can try position relative to the `section-2` and then use the `top` property to make it overlay on the header.

Or

```css
.section-2 {
  background: blue;
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: -30px auto;
}
```

You can use a negative top margin to pull the container up and use `auto` for the left and right margins to center the container.

```css
.section-1 {
  background: wheat;
  height: 100px;
}

.section-2 {
  background: blue;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: -30px auto 0;
}
.section-3 {
  background: green;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-1"></div>
<div class="section-2"></div>
<div class="section-3"></div>
```

Comment: in this case section 3 is being displayed after section 2

Comment: That is the requirement right?

Comment: no, section 1 and then section 3. section 2 is overlapping both section 1, section 3

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.container{
  height:100vh;
}    
.section-1{
  height:25vh;
  background-color: #1B80CE;    
}
.section-2{
  height:67.5vh;
  width:80%;
  margin-left:10%;
  margin-top:-12.5vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.section-3{
  height:100vh;
  background-color: #E8EBF0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="section-3">
     <div class="section-1">...</div>
     <div class="section-2">...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to fill the rest with section 3 rather than the body.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code. Let me know if this is what you were expecting.

Comment: not exactly, this is more like workaround. I do not want section 1 to be in scope of section 3. Anyway I have added the solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.container{
  height:100vh;
}    
.section-1{
  height:25vh;
  background-color: #1B80CE;    
}
.section-2{
  height:67.5vh;
  width:80%;
  margin-left:10%;
  margin-top:-12.5vh;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}
.section-3{
  height:75vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #E8EBF0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="section-1">...</div>
   <div class="section-3">
     
     <div class="section-2">...</div>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```